# VBA Data Sort and Format

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

[image: sheet1]
This is the raw data.

[image: sheet2]
This is what the data should look like but won't for reasons listed below.

**The problem i run into is that sometimes entire headers and data values are missing in the dataset and therefore using the last row in the script the data is shifted up by one.** For example, if i removed H11:H12 completely on sheet1 then the values for the H column associated with the data set in A11:K11 will actually be from the data set A13:K13 (or cell value H14).

**The spaces shown in the second image would not be present if the respective header is not present.**

**Question:** Given the following code; Do you think it is possible to match the data to headers and use the original offset row number alongside the column that it is matched to on sheet 2 and paste the values there? Instead the current code (and only method that worked was to find the last row).

**Examples/Thoughts:**
I'm thinking that the script will have to take a cell (such as D9 and recognizes it is a D and offsets to select D10 and matches that D9 record to sheet 2 column D and pastes the D10 data in D10 rather than D5.

second example, Script takes I17 and recognizes it matches I to sheet 2 column I and then offsets to select/copy and pastes the I19 data in I18 rather than I9.

```
Sub main()
    Dim hedaerCell As Range
    Dim labelsArray As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") '<--| reference your "headers" worksheet
        For Each hedaerCell In .Range("A1:K1") '<--| loop through all "headers"
            labelsArray = GetValues(hedaerCell.Value) '<--| fill array with all labels found under current "header"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, hedaerCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(labelsArray)).Value = Application.Transpose(labelsArray)
            Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetValues(header As String) As Variant
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iFound As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange '<--| reference your "data" worksheet
        ReDim labelsArray(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, header)) As Variant '<--| size an array to store as many "labels" as passed 'header' occurrences
        Set f = .Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| start seraching for passed 'header'
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                iFound = iFound + 1
                labelsArray(iFound) = f.Offset(1)
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    GetValues = labelsArray
End Function
```

The data in the photos is not the actual data but rather it is just placeholders. A to K represent the category headers. Any number or special character denotes the data that is being collected under each category. As you may notice some categories do not have a value for the particular data set (row number). I can't find a way for it to copy over the blank cells to the second sheet. Instead under the current code it simply ignores any blanks.

I was thinking that if anyone had any knowledge that could help me match the data to respective headers to find the right column to paste but still retain the original row number that it had in the raw data sheet then it would fix the issue of the code failing to copy blank cells and would keep the individual data sets together.

**Update:**I have created a link to an example document.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/03p8n1u9y9nvbd5/Example.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's probably a good idea to avoid typos in your variable names, like `hedaerCell` (especially if you're not using `Option Explicit`).

Comment: Can you describe your pictures? Assuming first one is the "input" and second one is the "output" but is it the correct output? If not, also please include a picture of what the correct output should look like. My suspicion is that you're making this overly complicated, especially if the data is normalized, you should be able to copy entire rows at a time, skipping every odd row which has the A/B/C/etc in it.

Comment: Gotcha, ill go back and fix any typos.

So the first image is the input and the second is what the output should look like. With the code i have however, when it is searching through a row (think of rows as individual data sets) and it picks up say an "H" column header with a blank cell beneath it, it does not copy it. 

Instead it will leave it blank and because I use the last empty row in my code, when it reads the next row it will copy any H column value to the data set that had previously had a blank value.

Comment: edit your question to include the details, don't assume anyone else will read the comments :)

Comment: I think in the sample workbook I touch on one more issue that would prevent me from just skipping every odd row and copying the entire line. The issue i have is that when i receive the raw data the column headers are not always in a neat order like A-K, instead there will be some data entries that are missing say, F and G column headers and values entirely and the rest of that row will have their data in the following order A,B,C,D,E,H,I,J,K so i'm forced to rely on matching headers to headers.

Comment: Why are you posting the same question over and over? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831044/vba-data-sorting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700414/vba-sorting-of-data

Comment: Nobody is going to download a random file from the internet, you need to work on revising/reframing your question so that it can be asked concisely,w ithout requiring people to download random XLSM files.

Comment: @Blackhawk thanks for noticing that, dupe questions have been hammered.

Comment: Ah, yeah someone that commented before had asked me if i could include an example file, but that is completely true. I'll work on the clarity.

Comment: How can i delete past questions?

Comment: Underneath the question body, there are several links for `share edit close delete flag protect` (YMMV). Click the "delete" option. I'd recommend deleting all three of these and asking anew.

Comment: Gotcha, It won't let me delete it. Give me 2 minutes to copy the comments and question and i'll post it under the same heading. Unless you believe there is a better way to ask this question that might direct it to the right user base?

Comment: Yeah I mean I guess ask a new one anyways. The problem is that questions, once closed, are not likely to be re-opened especially in this tag which doesn't get a tremendous amount of traffic. Not sure why you can't delete your own question, though.  In your new Q, make it clear upfront that you're asking a new question because your previous attempts were closed/unclear/etc., and you're trying to improve the question as a new one.

Comment: Are you able to delete?
When I try it simply redirects to the "duplicate question" and then its just a loop.

Comment: ah so questions need to be reopened to have the option to delete once they are flagged as duplicate.